# execute select query into WITH variable

Tags: postgresql, function

Normally, I write function in postgres like below

```
with detail_data as(
select
    id
from
    product p
where
    category = PARAM1_HERE 
order by update_time)
```

Now I want to change query to dynamic order. I tried as below

```
with detail_data as( 
execute 'select id from product p where category  = $1 order by $2'
    using PARAM1_HERE,PARAM2_HERE)
```

I get an error when compile:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "execute"

How do i resolve it?

Comment: You make the complete query dynamic, not just the one inside the first CTE.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because `EXECUTE` is a PL/pgSQL command, not a `SQL` one - in case you're **not** working with prepared statements. That being said, you might wanna try using a real function.

Test data

```
CREATE TABLE product (id INT, category INT, txt TEXT);
INSERT INTO product VALUES (1,1,'x'),(42,1,'f'),(8,1,'a'),(2,1,'j');
```

Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cte_function(INT,TEXT) 
RETURNS TABLE(res INT) AS $$
BEGIN  
RETURN QUERY 
  EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT id FROM product WHERE category=%L ORDER BY %I',$1,$2);
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Testing (order by id)

```
SELECT * FROM cte_function(1,'id') ;
 res 
-----
   1
   2
   8
  42
(4 rows)
```

Testing (order by txt)

```
SELECT * FROM cte_function(1,'txt') ;
 res 
-----
   8
  42
   2
   1
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I don't want to write another function, is it have another way?

Comment: @Tuấn I'm not aware of a way to dynamically write **column names** in pure SQL statements. The closer you get is using `PREPARE`, but variables are only used for values and not for columns.

Comment: @Tuấn btw, this would be a way to use a prepared statement (without ordering):

`PREPARE mystm AS SELECT id FROM product WHERE category=$1;
 EXECUTE mystm (1);`